# How to find an objects (which contains fields) in Motor MongoDB by entering its incomplete or inaccurate name?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, motordriver

I am creating an economic Discord bot on **PyCord** with a shop where items can be added. I want it to be possible to purchase an item without entering its exact name, and if multiple items are found, a list of found items should be displayed. The user can then simply choose the item (I can do this myself).

However, I ran into the problem of searching for objects in MongoDB, I tried to use the **$regex** operator, but it didn't find anything.

**I want the search to be done something like this**: The user enters a query with the name of the item, most likely not accurate, not complete, etc., but for the bot to try to find this item.
For example:

## Request: "item"

## Database:

```
 Shop: Object
    Items: Object
        Item A: Object
            price: 280
        Item B: Object
            price: 250
        Item C: Object
            price: 200
            description: "Good Item"
```

In this case, it should find all the Item objects (A, B, C), and output them as a list and the user will have to choose one (I can figure this out myself)
I hope my question was clear :)

## My code:

```py
search = await economy_db.find_one({"_id": ctx.guild.id, "Shop.Items": {"$regex": "item"}})
```

Comment: Is `Items` an array? Are the names of the objects (e.g. `Item A`) being used as fields instead of values? If so, that's going to significantly complicate your query

Comment: @user20042973 No, Items are not an array. No field names are being used as fields, they are objects that store fields within themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `find_one` which always returns one object.
You should be using the `find` method which returns all the documents that satisfy the query.

Adding the usage of `re` (python regular expression module) gives:

```py
import re

matching_items = list(economy_db.find({'Shop.Items': re.compile(<YOUR_REGEX>)}))
```

Or use the `$regex` operator in MongoDB:

```py
matching_items = list(economy_db.find({'Shop.Items': {'$regex': <YOUR_REGEX>}}))
```

Mind two caveats:

1. If you want the regex search to be case insensitive then in the first example you should add `re.IGNORECASE` to the `compile` function. And `$options: 'i'` to the `$regex` operator in the second example.
2. I did not include the `"_id": ctx.guild.id` part as it is unique to each document, and we want all the documents which their item name satisfies the regex search.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The problem is that you need to look not at all documents, but only at one because each server has its shop and its document

Comment: @Feor Then in that case you can use `find_one` :-)

Comment: I just checked this code, but it didn't find anything even when I entered the exact name of one of the items

Comment: Based on your code, specifically the example using re.compile, I was able to solve my problem. Here is my code:

```python
guild_id = await economy_db.find_one({"_id": ctx.guild.id})
found_items = []
items = search.get("Shop", {}).get("Items", {})
for item in items:
   pattern = re.compile("item", re.IGNORECASE)
   if pattern.search(item):
      found_items.append(item)
```